# Layout with two TextViews

Tags: android, layout, android-layout

I'm trying to design a layout with two TextViews:

```
|                                                     |
| (Multilined Textview) (60dp TextView)               |
| (of unknown size    )                               |
```

If first TextView has little text, it should look like this:

```
|                                                     |
| (Hello!) (12:34:56)                                 |
|                                                     |
```

If first TextView has many text, it should look like this:

```
|                                                     |
| (Ey! This is a very very very very long) (12:34:56) |
| (message.                              )            |
```

Somebody knows how to achieve this?

Thank you very much.

EDIT: I got it working. Solution in my own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:padding_right = 'fix value of width of TextView text 2'
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:gravity="left" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text_1"
        android:gravity="center" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I like the idea! But text_2 layouts to right to text_1, including padding, so I get text_1+60sp+text_2. Any way to layout to right of an element ignoring padding?

Comment: I think you can try to use android:minHeight as Mr. Binh said.

Comment: Hey!!! I applied a little hack to your solution, and now it works! I'm adding it to my question.

Comment: I mark your solution as accepted, even it didn't work without the hack. I'll upvote you when I get a reputation of 15. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can achieve this with a weighted `LinearLayout`:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:weightSum="1">

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Update:** An alternative solution you may also want to try (possibly even with conjunction to the weighted `LinearLayout`):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxWidth="200dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Good idea, thanks. The problem with that solution is that when first layout has little text, the "free space" goes between the TextViews (the first TextView takes all free space, actually), but I need that free space to be at right.

Comment: @mavnaranjo I updated my answer. Hopefully that gives you the effect you're looking for.

Comment: The idea is that first TextViews can take all the space it needs, but just the space it needs, and the remaining free space to be at right. So the maxWidth doesn't solve the problem. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`. 
If you textview is initialized with empty string, you should use `android:minHeight="100dp"` to set minimize width also.

Comment: The first textview can't be empty, it will have at least 1 character, but even in that case, I wan't it to take just the minimun space it needs.

Comment: You can set empty string to your textview by android:text="" or txtName.setText(""). I am sorry for my mistake about minimize width, please use android:minWidth="100dp" instead of android:minHeight="100dp"

Comment: Of course it can be empty, I meant that it shouldn't be empty. The layout is for a instant messaging application, the first TextView is the message, and the second TextView is the timestamp, so both of them are never empty. Don't worry about the minHeight mistake, I understood what you tried to say :).

Answer (score 0):

Here I put my final solution:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/variable_size_textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:paddingRight="60sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/hack"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/variable_size_textview" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/fixed_size_textview"
    android:layout_width="60sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/hack" />
```